# Unknown provider for service during unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, typescript

Error during execution ..

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: secondServiceProvider <- secondService
```

my.component.controller.ts

```
import { FirstService } from '../../first.service';
import { SecondService } from '../../second.service';

export class MyComponentController {
  constructor(
    public $state: ng.ui.IStateService,
    private firstService: FirstService,
    private secondService: SecondService) { }
}

MyComponentController.$inject = [
  '$state', 
  FirstService.registeredName, 
  SecondService.registeredName];
```

my.component.spec.ts

```
import { FirstService } from '../../first.service';
import { SecondService } from '../../second.service';
import { MyModule } from '../index';

describe('Component: my', () => {

  let $componentController: angular.IComponentControllerService;
  let firstService: FirstService;
  let secondService: SecondService;
  let scope: angular.IScope;
  let $state: ng.ui.IStateService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module('ui.router');
    angular.mock.module(MyModule.name);
  });

  beforeEach(inject(
    ($rootScope: angular.IScope,
      _$state_: ng.ui.IStateService,
      _$componentController_: angular.IComponentControllerService) => {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $state = _$state_;
      firstService = new FirstService();
      secondService = new SecondService();
      $componentController = _$componentController_;
    }));

  describe('Controller: MyComponentController', () => {
    it('should create an instance of MyComponentController', () => {
      let ctrl: any = $componentController('my', { $scope: scope }, { $state: $state, firstService: firstService, secondService: secondService });
      expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$componentController` was used incorrectly. The third argument is bindings. Mocked services are dependencies, so is `$scope`. It should be:

```
$componentController('my', {
  $scope: scope, $state: $state, firstService: firstService, secondService: secondService
});
```

There's absolutely no point in providing real dependencies this way, they would be provided by default. As a rule of thumb, all units but tested unit (a controller) should be mocked or stubbed.

Real router should not be used in unit tests. `ui.router` should be excluded and its services should be mocked or stubbed, if necessary.